# Why this command isn't possible in RiscV?

Tags: cpu, pipeline, clock, cpu-registers, riscv

In my textbook I saw the following question:

Can we implement the following operation (changes are allowed):

```
dam rd ,rs, imm # reg[rd]=mem[mem[rs+imm]]
```

1. In Riscv-Single Cycle

2. In RiscV Multi Cycle - Pipeline

The answer for both was wrong, can someone explain why?

For 1 the book wrote because we can't read twice from memory in single cycle but what's the problem? I know we can't write twice because each time we want to write the clock should be up.

Comment: Hypotheticals are really hard to reason about.  We don't know what book, what changes are allowed, the exact nature of either the single cycle or multi-cycle pipeline, or what was "wrong" in the answers.

Comment: There's a data dependency between the two reads.  That means that the 2nd read can't start until the first is finished and provides a result.  It would be very hard to start the 2nd read without another clock edge.  One might use the falling edge of the clock but of course some would reasonably argue that is no longer single cycle.

Comment: A pipelined processor could add another data memory pipeline stage, but the data memory (i.e. the cache) would have to be dual ported, since both data memory pipeline stages could be active at the same time.